# Property 'SetShowInEditForm' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.- SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell, spfield, hidden

I'm trying to make a field in Edit mode hidden by using this code below :-

```
$web = $context.Web
$site = $context.Site 
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test List");

$fields = $list.Fields["TestHidden"];

# Controls Field in Edit Form
$fields.SetShowInEditForm = $false;
$fields.Update();
$list.Update();

$context.ExecuteQuery();
```

But i'm getting the error:- Property 'SetShowInEditForm' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.- SharePoint Online

Any ideas what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

In SPO, the `SetShowInEditForm` is a method and not a property.

You can "set" the value as below:

`$fields.SetShowInEditForm($false);`

Reference - [Field.SetShowInEditForm method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field.setshowineditform.aspx)

Comment: THanks for that.
But now i get error:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Powershell\HideColumnINModes.ps1:20 char:1
+ $fields.SetShowInEditForm($false);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Got it.Changed my code to
$field = $list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("TestHidden");